# Problemas con los decimales al generar un archivo de Excel con php

Tags: php, php7, phpexcel

Buenos días tengo un inconveniente al hacer una operación en php y después pasar el dato a Excel debido a que el dato resultante es un decimal, en mi Excel como esta en español me muestra bien el resultado pero el del cliente esta el office en ingles y me corre la coma un espacio, he intentado con puntos y tampoco funciona, alguien me puede indicar como solucionarlo.

Esta es la operación y el resultado que me da a mi

```
$horasTotales = ((60 * $horas) + $minutos) / 60;
$horasTotales = 60*3 + 07 / 60;
$horasTotales = 3,116;
```

Este es el resultado que le da al cliente en el Excel

```
$horasTotales = ((60 * $horas) + $minutos) / 60;
$horasTotales = 60*3 + 07 / 60;
$horasTotales = 31,16;
```

Comment: Podrías verificar la configuración regional de tu maquina y compararla con la del cliente, muchas veces pasa que es solo eso ya que en latam generalmente se usa el punto como separador de miles y en USA o en sistemas anglosajones se usa la coma para tal fin.

Comment: y no hay alguna forma de que pueda hacer algo en php para que quede funcionando en office que sean tanto en español e ingles?

Comment: Se me ocurre que el problema se da por la cantidad de decimales. Intenta aplicarle [`round()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.round.php) al resultado.